# Typescript AngularJS access form object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am using AngularJS and Typescript.

I got a problem trying to access the form object.

Following is my HTML

```
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>

    <label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="frm.FirstName" name="FirstName"    />
<button ng-click="logit()"></button>
</form>
```

Now i want to access the frm object my typescript code is as follows

```
module TestCtrl{
    interface ITestController{
        logit(): any;
    }

    class TestController implements ITestController{

        frm: any;
        constructor() {
            var vm = this;
            var frm = {};

        }

        logit(){
            var vm;
            console.log(frm.FirstName);
        }

    }

    angular.module('app').controller('TestCtrl', TestController);
}
```

The console says frm is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `this.frm.FirstName`. Your typescript compiler should have catched this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
module TestCtrl{
    interface ITestController{
        logit(): void;
        frm: any;
    }

    class TestController implements ITestController{

        frm: any;
        constructor() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.frm = {};

        }

        logit(){
            console.log(this.frm.FirstName);
        }

    }
    angular.module('app').controller('TestCtrl', TestController);
}
```

What you got to remember that `var vm = this;` is just a way of storing your current scope. And typescript does a pretty good job of doing that in the first place. So it won't **generally** make a difference you putting `vm` in.

You may also want to think about typing your form out as well.

```
interface IFormViewModel {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

thus making your `ITestController`

```
interface ITestController{
    logit(): void;
    frm: IFormViewModel;
}

class TestController implements ITestController{
    frm: IFormViewModel;

    constructor() {
        this.frm = {};
    }

    logit(){
        console.log(this.frm.firstName);
    }
}
angular.module('app').controller('TestCtrl', TestController);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of typing the form, very convenient actually. Regarding the logit function it console.logs undefined as it seems not to be able to find the FirstName any ideas why?

Comment: yeah you need to remember to use the `ControllerAs` syntax when specifying where to use the controller otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Do you know how i can console.log myForm.FirstName the only way so far is this.$scope.myForm.FirstName any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, You can access the model inside the controller using `$scope` variable.
In your case it would be

```
$scope.frm = {};
console.log($scope.frm.FirstName);
```